# Dropdown list in Flash Banner

Tags: flash, actionscript, clicktag

I am building a flash banner ad that contains a dropdown list of US states. Once the list is clicked I want to pass the state code onto the end of the url for the ad.

I used to be ok with actionscript but it was several years ago, and I'm wondering if its possible to have the ad grab the URL from the parent `<a href>` and just tack the state code onto it.  I assume this is how clickTags work?

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(clickTAG, "_top");
  }
}
```

Can anyone offer any tips on how best to do this? I'm fine with building the actual ad, its just I'm not sure if I need to hard code 50 urls into my dropdown? It seems a bad way of doing things, and I'm sure theres a better way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clickTAG is a string which is the URL that has been put as a parameter in the embed code, and is the URL to click through to.

Since, it's just a string, you can add whatever you need to it programmatically.

I would do it this way:

Say you want to add argument to the end of the URL like ?state=NY

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
     var url:String;
     url = clickTAG + dropDownMenu.getCurrentStateCode() // I'm not sure how your drop down works, so this last part is just pseudocode.

  getURL(url, "_top");
  }
}
```